# Redirect to URL on Placeholder Click

Tags: html

I have some code here that creates an animated search bar:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever somebody clicks on it, the search bar expands and lets the user type the keyword(s). How would I make it so that when the user clicks on the search bar, it waits (e.g 1 secs) for the search bar to expand and then redirects to a URL. Do I change the `input[type=text]` to `input[type=code]` and do the same with `input[type=text]:focus`???? Please don't give too complicated answers and I am just a beginner. I looked up most directions to insert the code but my website does not support the site.com/?search=keywords. Please help!!

Thanks,
- Will

Comment: btw for the redirection youre talking about, have you tried to use Javascript?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to URL when someone clicks on search? That seems illogical. The search should redirect to URL **after** the user types the search query **and then** when he/she presses `Enter` or clicks on the search button should the search bar redirect to different URL.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with JS :

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onClick="redirect()">
</form>
```

And :

```
<script>
    function redirect() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css propert for transition, "transition-delay" here is the code example. [Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny9jphup/)

```
input[type=text] {
width: 130px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('searchicon.png');
background-position: 10px 10px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
transition-delay: 2s;
```

}

```
input[type=text]:focus {
   width: 100%;
}
```